# Why CMSAdapter and contenthub is not available?

Tags: semantic-web, apache-stanbol

As per Stanbol [documentation](https://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/tutorial.html), I've checked-out source code (% svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/trunk stanbol)  and after did maven build. All is fine. Now I've started executable jar (org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT).

After starting this I do not see any menu option to open CMSAdapter and contenthub. I can only see /enhancer, /topic, /entityhub, /sparql, /ontonet,  /rules, and /reasoners  in the menu option. 
Here is the localhost page - 
[image]

When I saw the checked-out directory then I did not find folders corresponding to cmsadpater and contenthub.

[image]

After I tried to [download](http://a.mbbsindia.com/stanbol/apache-stanbol-contenthub-0.10.0-source-release.zip) complete zip from source again and now i can see cmsadpater and contenthub - 
[image]

But I'm getting error during build.
Please suggest what I'm missing here.

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.stanbol:org.apache.stanbol.launchers.full:jar:0.12.0: Failure to find org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.launchpad:xml:bundlelist:8 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Answer (score 1):

ContentHub and CMSAdapter components have been discontinued from version 1.x. You can still find them at 0.12.x branch (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/stanbol/branches/release-0.12/)

Hope that helps